# How do II get object with the the largest value of a certain field in my Django model objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm am trying to create a view where the user will get the object with the largest value of a certain field in my Django model objects.

This is my model:

```
class LongTermCoinHistory(models.Model):
    coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

I want to get the object instance from my database that has the largest timestamp value.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Try this to get the item with the highest timestamp `LongTermCoinHistory.objects.order_by('-timestamp').first()`

Comment: This is working correctly. However I want to do a filter as well.
What I have is this:
a = Coin.objects.get(ticker= coinname)
queryset = LongTermCoinHistory.objects.filter(coin = a)

How do I add the order_by with the filter?

Comment: You can chain these methods: `LongTermCoinHistory.objects.filter(coin = a).order_by('-timestamp').first()`

Comment: That is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
LongTermCoinHistory.objects.latest("timestamp")
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest)